Typescript json require() function isn't reading directory from a variable
I have a variable jsonDir which is equal to "./smallsample.json".
The following line
const data = require(jsonDir);
Always raises the error Error: Cannot find module './smallsample.json'
However, if I write const data = require("./smallsample.json"); it works correctly.
I wrote the following code for testing, the first require() will load correctly but the second will throw an error (even if I test them one by one).
  console.log(jsonDir === "./smallsample.json"); //returns true
  const data = require("./smallsample.json"); //reads correctly
  const data2 = require(jsonDir); //throws error

Since both functions have the exact same parameter, I do not know what could be causing this.

I suspect this has something to do with your build system/bundler. Looks like a symptom of a transformation that works in literal case but not with anything more complex.

Try to add "resolveJsonModule": true, to your tsconfig.json

I already had "resolveJsonModule": true, there.

Are you using webpack to compile that, or just plain nodejs? Or are you using library called requirejs?

I am using plain nodejs. I mistakenly put the requirejs tag on my post, I will remove it.
